# How to send Json data to an API in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, api

I have the following on my frontend:
Note: My JSON file in a state

```
    const postData = () => {
        console.log("This is our data", state);
        const url = "http://localhost:3000/postData";
        fetch(url, 
        {method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        body: JSON.stringify(state),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});

}
```

This front end is working. However, I want to post this data to an API such that when someone types:

**localhost:3000/postData**

They must get my JSON file that was in my state on the front end

Here is the backend code that I'm struggling with:

```
app.post("/postData", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const result = req.body.state
    res.send(result);

});
```

Comment: Is it not giving you the data you expected ?

Comment: No, it's not. The backend is not working

Comment: can you provide the data that you are sending and what you are receiving at the backend?

Answer (score 0):

```
body: JSON.stringify({
            state: state,
        })
```

Comment: This must be added?

Comment: replace
body: JSON.stringify(state)
to
body: JSON.stringify({
             state: state
         })

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way

```
this.apiService.post('URl', body).then((data) => {
            if (data) {
            }
        });
```